# Add corresponding OLE object (image) in table through button on form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table Students with the following fields: Voornaam, Achternaam and Foto. The fields Voornaam and Achternaam are filled in with the students firstname and lastname. The field Foto (Picture) is empty. Because I don't want to manually add every picture of the students I wanted to do it with some code.

I have a form where I put the records and I have a button to load the photos in the empty fields. I also have a textbox where I could say where he has to look for the photos.

This is my code:

> Sub cmdLoad_Click()
>
> ```
> Dim db As DAO.Database
> Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
> Dim query As String
>
> Dim MyFolder As String
> Dim MyPath As String
> Dim MyFile As String
>
> 'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
>
> Set db = CurrentDb
> query = "Select * FROM tblStudents"
> Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(query, dbOpenDynaset)
>
> MyFolder = Me!txtFolder
>
> 'Wanneer er geen items zijn. Sluiten
> If rs.EOF Then Exit Sub
>
> With rs
>     Do Until rs.EOF
>         MyPath = MyFolder & "\" & [Voornaam] & " " & [Achternaam] & ".jpg"
>         MyFile = Dir(MyPath, vbNormal)
>
>         rs.Edit
>
>         [Foto].Class = "Paint.Picture"
>         [Foto].OLETypeAllowed = acOLEEmbedded
>         [Foto].SourceDoc = MyPath
>         [Foto].Action = acOLECreateEmbed
>
>         rs.Update
>         rs.MoveNext
>    Loop
> End With
>
> rs.Close
> db.Close
> Set rs = Nothing
> Set db = Nothing
>
> Exit Sub
>
> ErrorHandler:    MsgBox "Test Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf &
>     vbCrLf & Err.Description End Sub
> ```

I iterate on the results of the table. At every record I edit it and I want to add the picture to the foto field, but here's the problem.

When I click the button to load in, I get the following error:

> a error occurred while microsoft access was communicating with the ole
>   server or activex control
>   .

When I debug it's on this line where it goes wrong:

> [Foto].Action = acOLECreateEmbed

I've tried to find a solution, but so far I couldn't find it. I hope the problem is a bit clear. Or is there a better solution?

Comment: If memory serves me correct this generally comes down to a missing reference or simply just importing all of your project pieces into a new project.  The second option has fixed that error message for me twice so far.

Comment: Ok, I will try. I tried it once, but I might have done something wrong.

Comment: Other than that after reaching the third page of Google I gave up on finding the answer.  Many people have posted the question, no one has answered.  Closest thing to a genre of suggestions was something to do with an antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

I store my user photos, documents etc as BLOB.

Avoids the overhead of OLE embed or link;

http://www.ammara.com/articles/imagesaccess.html

To load;

```
Private Sub cmdLoadImageClient_Click()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strname As String

    strname = Form_subfrmClientDetailsAAClient.FirstName & Form_subfrmClientDetailsAAClient.Surname

    strFile = fGetFile("Image", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png")
    If Len(strFile) > 0 Then
        If InsertBLOB("tblzBLOBClientPics", CStr(TempVars!frmClientOpenID), strname, "ClientPic", strFile) Then Call ShowImageClient
    End If

End Sub
```

To delete;

```
Private Sub cmdDeleteImageClient_Click()
    Dim strname As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strname = Form_subfrmClientDetailsAAClient.FirstName & Form_subfrmClientDetailsAAClient.Surname

    i = MsgBox("Do you want to Delete the Image for; " & strname & "?", vbOKCancel, "Beresford Financial.")

    Select Case i
        Case vbOK
            dbLocal.Execute "DELETE FROM tblzBLOBClientPics WHERE ClientID = '" & CStr(TempVars!frmClientOpenID) & "' AND ClientName = '" & strname & "' AND BLOBDesc = 'ClientPic'"
            Me.ProfilePicClient.Picture = ""
        Case vbCancel
    End Select
End Sub
```

To view;

```
Public Sub ShowImageClient()
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strname As String
On Error GoTo errHere

    Me.ProfilePicClient.Picture = ""
    strTemp = CurrentProject.Path & "\Temp.jpg"

    strname = Nz(Form_subfrmClientDetailsAAClient.FirstName) & Nz(Form_subfrmClientDetailsAAClient.Surname)

    If ExtractBLOB("tblzBLOBClientPics", CStr(TempVars!frmClientOpenID), strname, "ClientPic", strTemp) Then
        If Len(Dir(strTemp)) > 0 Then
            Me.ProfilePicClient.Picture = strTemp
            Kill strTemp
        End If
    End If

Exit Sub

errHere:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End Sub
```

BLOB Functions;

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function InsertBLOB(tblBLOB As String, ClientID As String, ClientName As String, strDesc As String, strFileName As String) As Boolean
'Inserts BLOB into table tblzBLOBDocuments
On Error GoTo CloseUp

    Dim objStream As Object 'ADODB.Stream
    Dim objCmd As Object 'ADODB.Command
    Dim varFileBinary

    'Empty any matching record
    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM " & tblBLOB & " WHERE ClientID = '" & ClientID & "' AND ClientName = '" & ClientName & "' AND BLOBDesc = '" & strDesc & "'"

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile strFileName
    varFileBinary = objStream.Read
    objStream.Close
    Set objStream = Nothing

    Set objCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    With objCmd
        .CommandText = "PARAMETERS paramID Text(255), paramTable Text(255), paramDesc Text(255), paramExtn Text(5), paramFile LongBinary;" & _
                        "INSERT INTO " & tblBLOB & " (ClientID, ClientName, BLOBDesc, FileExtn, BLOB) " & _
                        "SELECT paramID, paramTable, paramDesc, paramExtn, paramFile"
        .CommandType = 1 'adCmdText
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("paramID", 200, 1, 255, ClientID)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("paramTable", 200, 1, 255, ClientName)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("paramDesc", 200, 1, 255, strDesc)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("paramExtn", 200, 1, 5, right(strFileName, Len(strFileName) - InStrRev(strFileName, ".")))
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("paramFile", 205, 1, 2147483647, varFileBinary)
        Set .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
        .Execute , , 128
    End With

    InsertBLOB = True

CloseUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objStream = Nothing
    Set objCmd = Nothing

End Function

Function ExtractBLOB(tblBLOB As String, ClientID As String, ClientName As String, strDesc As String, ByRef strFileName As String) As Boolean
'Extracts specified BLOB to file from table tblzBLOBDocuments

    Dim strSql As String
    Dim rst As Object 'ADODB.Recordset
    Dim objStream As Object 'ADODB.Stream

    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    strSql = "SELECT FileExtn, BLOB FROM " & tblBLOB & " WHERE ClientID = '" & ClientID & "' AND ClientName = '" & ClientName & "' AND BLOBDesc = '" & strDesc & "'"
    rst.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection, 1, 3
    If rst.RecordCount = 0 Then
        GoTo CloseUp
    End If

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objStream
        .Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write rst.Fields("BLOB").Value
        If Not IsNull(rst!FileExtn) Then
            strFileName = Left(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, ".")) & rst!FileExtn
        End If
        .SaveToFile strFileName, 2 'adSaveCreateOverWrite
    End With

    ExtractBLOB = True

CloseUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set objStream = Nothing
End Function
```

Filepicker;

```
Function fGetFile(strType As String, strExt As String, Optional strPath As String)

    With Application.FileDialog(3) ' 3=msoFileDialogFilePicker 4=msoFileDialogFolderPicker
'        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm", 1
        .Filters.Add strType, strExt, 1
        If strPath <> "" Then
            .InitialFileName = strPath    ' start in this folder
        End If
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show

        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
'           MsgBox .SelectedItems(1)
            fGetFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

tblzBLOBClientPics;

```
ClientID   Short Text
ClientName Short Text
BLOBDesc   Short Text
FileExtn   Short Text
BLOB       OLE Object
```

Comment: Ok, going to give this a try!

Comment: @Rafie How did you go with it?

Comment: I haven't found the time yet (it's a side project) :( I'm hoping to implement it this weekend.