# What is the correct syntax for programmatically creating a Word document in an OLEBoundFrame in ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ole

I need to automatically create a Word.Document object in a BoundObjectFrame which is tied to an OLE field in my database.

In the AfterInsert event of the form I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    Dim oDocument As Object
    Dim rsParaRS As Recordset
    Dim intCurrline As Integer
    With OLEBoundWord
        .Class = "Word.Document"
        .Action = acOLECreateEmbed(0)

    End With

'    OLEBoundWord.CreateEmbed vbNullString, "Word.Document"
    Set oDocument = OLEBoundWord.Object
    Set rsParaRS = Form.Recordset
    rsParaRS.MoveLast
    rsParaRS.Edit
    rsParaRS!ParagraphOrder = rsParaRS.RecordCount
    rsParaRS!ParagraphDocE = oDocument
    rsParaRS.Update
    ' rsParaRS.Close
End Sub
```

When I try to run the code I get an "expected array" error at the point where the .Action = acOLECreateEmbed(0) is invoked. How or where do I initialize the array for acOLECreateEmbed, or is there something else that I'm missing?

Any thoughts/pointers?

Comment: Similar question and unfortunately no solution found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930240/add-corresponding-ole-object-image-in-table-through-button-on-form-in-ms-acces. Another with semi-working code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60494121/ms-access-add-ole-objects-to-table-with-vba

Comment: I have progressed somewhat by changing to .Class="Excel.Sheet"  instead of "Word.Document" and removed the (0) after the .Action = acOLECreateEmbed line. If I try it with .Class="Word.Document" I get an error that "the class argument given for createobject function is invalid".

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work by moving my BoundObjectFrame to a separate form that did not have a datasheet view - the one I couldn't get to work was in a datasheet row. On the new form's BoundObjectFrame GotFocus event I used the following code:

```
Private Sub OLEBoundWord_GotFocus()
    If IsNull(Me.OLEBoundWord.Value) Then
        With Me.OLEBoundWord
            .Class = "Word.Document"
            .Action = acOLECreateEmbed ''(0)

        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

That worked!

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that OP copied "acOLECreateEmbed(0)" from the [Office VBA Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa223899(v=office.11)). The **BoundObjectFrame.Action** property requires a constant. *acOLECreateEmbed* is a constant. See the [Object Browser pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QdSh.png) below. The statement, "acOLECreateEmbed(0)", implies to the compiler that *acOLECreateEmbed* is a function accepting a numeric parameter, or is an array.

I assume it's a given in your application that information will always be entered into a Word document immediately after each record insertion. Otherwise, object creation on that event will needlessly bloat the database. Bloat can be avoided by the strategy below.

```
Private Sub OLEWord_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

If IsNull(OLEWord.Value) Then 'Avoid overwriting edited document
    With OLEWord
        .Class = "Word.Document"
        .OLETypeAllowed = acOLEEmbedded
        .Action = acOLECreateEmbed
        .AutoActivate = acOLEActivateDoubleClick
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Setting **BoundObjectFrame.AutoActivate** to the constant
*acOLEActivateDoubleClick* opens the Word document on the *_DblClick* event. This can also be set at *BoundObjectFrame's* property sheet.The 
*_MouseDown* event will create the object just prior to *_DblClick* opening it for editing.

*Screenshot acOLECreateEmbed is a Constant*

[image: Access Object Browser Pic]